# using inotifywait in a script to automate a git commit when files have been added to git repository via FTP

Tags: linux, git, web, workflow, inotify

I've got a git workflow set up similar to this http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/.   Essentially i have local repositories that report to a remote repository that is bare.  Then I have my deployment directory accessible via web also set up as a repository that also reports to the same bare repository.

It's set up with git hooks so that when local developer pushes changes to remote repository, hook goes into web folder and pulls from the repository so it always has the latest and greatest.  All works pretty good.

My crux is that I'm looking to appease to the people who don't want to you GIT and just want to upload files to the web folder via FTP.   I've kinda got this working by setting up an inotifywait monitor on the web folder for whenever files are written, modified, moved, deleted, created, etc...  my bash script for this is as follows.

```
!/bin/sh
inotifywait @*.swp -rm -e modify,move,create,delete,delete_self,unmount /var/www/html/mysite | while read
do

now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y:%T")
echo $now >> temp.txt

cd /var/www/html/mysite || exit
git add --all
git commit -m "ftp update $now" -a
done
```

This too actually works, but what I'm observing is that I'm stuck in the while loop once I trigger the inotifywait by modifying a file in my web folder.  Anyone have any ideas on this?  Ideally would love it to do it's thing and not be stuck in the while loop continuously running unnecessary git commands.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of inotfiywait?

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) suggests that you do a different loop style:

```
while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/messages; do
    …
done
```

have you tried that?